# Unable to start distributed tsung cluster

Tags: erlang, load-testing, tsung

I am trying to setup a distributed tsung cluster and am unable to get it running.

```
tsung -f tsung-script.xml start
Starting Tsung
"Log directory is: /home/ec2-user/.tsung/log/20140414-0158"
Host key verification failed.
```

I have tried the manual's suggesting of opening all ports, I am able to run tsung on both the controller and the slave. I get the same error if I try the test command in the debug section of the manual.

```
erl -rsh ssh -sname ec2-user -setcookie mycookie
slave:start("ip-XX-XXX-XXX-XXX.ec2.internal","ec2-user","-setcookie mycookie").
Host key verification failed.
```

I am able to ssh to the box without a password already (outside of tsung:)

```
ssh ip-XX-XXX-XXX-XXX.ec2.internal erl
Eshell V5.8.5  (abort with ^G)
1>
```

What else should I be checking? 
Is there something obvious I am missing?
Is there a way to get more detailed logs about what is failing and what is being attempted by erlang?

The current controller log is not helpful:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 14-Apr-2014::01:59:26 ===
              ts_mon:(5:<0.53.0>) Activate clients with text backend

=INFO REPORT==== 14-Apr-2014::01:59:26 ===
              ts_mon:(5:<0.53.0>) Starting tsung clients on hosts: ['ip-XX-XXX-XXX-XXX.ec2.internal']
```

Comment: "Host key verification failed" is not erlang error. It seems to be ssh error.

Comment: @OdobenusRosmarus Is there any way to get more information about what Tsung / Erlang is using to call tsung and why its broken through tsung?

Comment: well, I would try to establish ssh session from erlang, kind of application:start(crypto), ssh:start(), ssh:connect("yourhost",22,[]).  And look at result. Some detailed error message must appear.

Comment: So I chased down the issue, tsung requires you to setup /etc/host entries for the nodes even though they are DNS addressable. See here (http://lists.process-one.net/pipermail/tsung-users/2014-April/002981.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tsung Distributed Client Load Testing - Simple HTTP Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830625/tsung-distributed-client-load-testing-simple-http-requests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be the etc/hosts entries. Make sure the slaves have a host entry for the master and the master has host entries for itself and its slaves.

Answer (score 2):

I sometimes have this problem. I find deleting the know_hosts file from ~/.ssh helps